# Create a background thread in PHP that keeps running without user interaction

Tags: php

I need to create an application in php with a background thread containing an timer that keeps updating a database (by collecting data from different sites) separately without any user interference. What I mean by this is: without anybody visiting the site, the thread has to keep updating a database. Is this possible in PHP and how am I able to realise this ?

Comment: Use a cron file (crontab). Google it.

Comment: What OS are you on? What database are you using? What is the nature of the updates you wish to perform? How often?

Answer (score 3):

The best way I think it is to create a php script to do whatever you want and then set up a cron job to run that script at specific time.

Comment: I think codey55 is used to running PHP scripts from the webserver and hence the question.  Just like to add on that this is achieved using PHP as a command line http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for this:

- A scheduled task in your operating system, such as cron on *nix or Windows Scheduler for the Windows platform.
- A permanently running script. This is not ideal for PHP though, as memory usage is sometimes not correctly thrown away, and the script can run out of memory. It is common for scripts to be set to die and respawn, to prevent this from happening.
- A scheduled task in your database server. MySQL now supports this. If your purpose is to run database updates, this might be a good option, if you are running MySQL, and if your version is sufficiently recent.
- A queue, where some processing is done in the background upon a request signal. See Gearman, Resque and many others. It is useful where a user requests something in a web application, but that request is too lengthy to carry out immediately. If you need something to run permanently then this may not be ideal - I add it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Having a PHP process run for a long time isn't really a good idea because PHP isn't a very memory efficient language and PHP processes consume a lot of memory.

It would be better to use a job manager. Take a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Comment: The recommendation that PHP processes should not run for a long time is not about how memory efficient it is - it is that traditionally the garbage collector hasn't always freed up memory that is no longer in use (otherwise known as a "memory leak"). I believe this is much better in more recent versions of PHP, though.

Comment: Yeah, but what if you need to run a lot of background processes together? Surely you would want each one to consume a reasonable amount of memory, no?

Comment: Heh, of course. I was simply pointing out that the reason you gave for recommending against long-running PHP tasks is not the main reason for avoiding them.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't know that. Always good to learn something new!

Comment: I would like to run a PHP process that serves an in-memory database to my local network. Sounds simple, but I can't think of a simple way to do it.